# NullPointerException while accessing method in an object in 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2 dimensional array of "Node" objects as follows

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            length=getNumber("Enter the length of the field: ");
            breadth=getNumber("Enter the breadth of the filed: ");
            node n = new node();
            node [][] field = new node[length][breadth];
            for(i=0;i<=length;i++){
                for(j=0;j<=breadth;j++){
                    F =getNumber("Enter the F value");
                    field[i][j].setF(F);
                    System.out.println("  "+field[i][j].getF(F);
                }
            }

    }
```

in above code getNumber is a function wherein i print and accept the number
Here is my node class:

```
public class node {
public int F;
public int G;
public int H;
public boolean isVisited;
public boolean isCurrent;
public void node(int F,int G,int H,boolean isVisited, boolean isCurrent){
    this.F=F;
    this.G=G;
    this.H=H;
    this.isVisited=isVisited;
    this.isCurrent=isCurrent;

}
public int getF() {
    return G+H;
}
public void setF(int f) {
    F = f;
}
public int getG() {
    return G;
}
public void setG(int g) {
    G = g;
}
public int getH() {
    return H;
}
public void setH(int h) {
    H = h;
}
public boolean isVisited() {
    return isVisited;
}
public void setVisited(boolean isVisited) {
    this.isVisited = isVisited;
}
public boolean isCurrent() {
    return isCurrent;
}
public void setCurrent(boolean isCurrent) {
    this.isCurrent = isCurrent;
}
```

}

all i want to do is, to store/access various values of F,G,H etc in each of the node objects, the problem however is i'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` for `field[i][j].setF(F);`
i dont know where i'm going wrong, need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialized the array, but you did not populate it.

Consider this line:

`field[i][j].setF(F);`

When you do

`field[i][j]`

you are accessing the array; i.e. getting what is in the array at that position.  Since you didn't put anything in the array, you get a null.  But you immediately try to call `setF`.

I noticed you do

`node n = new node();`

outside the loop.  You probably want to do that in the loop.

```
node n = new node();
n.setF(F);
field[i][j] = n;
```

This code creates a `node` instance, sets a value on it, and then puts it in the array at the specified position.  A bit more fancy approach would be to do something like

```
node n = field[i][j];
if (n == null) { // initialize n at the position if it doesn't exist
  n = new node();
  field[i][j] = n;
}

field[i][j].setF(f);
```

Alternatively, you could loop over the array and put a new `node` at each position, right after you initialize the array.

Finally, in Java standard practice is to start class names with capital letters.  `node` should be `Node`.

Comment: what do i populate it with? since its an array of object (i'm a beginner so kindly elaborate on that)

Comment: @vineetrok  check out the bottom part of my answer, where I elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(i=0;i<=length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=breadth;j++){
        F =getNumber("Enter the F value");

        node tmp = new node();
        tmp.setF(F);

        field[i][j] = tmp;
        System.out.println("  "+field[i][j].getF(F);
    }
}
```

PS in java it is convention for class names to start with a capital and should be written in CamelCase

[edit]
Be careful with your get/setF() functions as they do not operate on the same variables

not related to your question, but you might want to read through this [document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) this will teach you about naming conventions in java and help you write code that is easier to read

Comment: using this i get field[i][j].getF(F)= 0

Comment: Ok, your "node" is not properly initialyzed, it has no constructor and the default one leaves G and H at 0... (your code is rather confusing here) because setF() actually sets F but getF() returns G+H.  Also the    public void node() is no constructor a constructor would be public node()